# How to initialize web app with dagger?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, servletcontextlistener

What do I need to add to the `contextInitialized` method to properly initialize the object graph?

Given this dagger module:

```
@Module
public class MapperModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

This subclass of ServletContextListener:

```
public class DaggerDi implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MapperModule());                
     }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }

}
```

And the web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.me.config.DaggerDi
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this dagger-servlet project](https://github.com/johnlcox/dagger-servlet), I have not tried it yet, but looks simple enough, you will have to:

1. Configure the servlet (web.xml file):

> ```
> <web-app>
>     <listener>
>         <listener-class>com.example.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
>     </listener>
>     <filter>
>         <filter-name>Dagger Filter</filter-name>
>         <filter-class>com.leacox.dagger.servlet.DaggerFilter</filter-class>
>     </filter>
>     <filter-mapping>
>         <filter-name>Dagger Filter</filter-name>
>         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>     </filter-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

2. Implement a context listener and module:

   @Module(injects = {...}, includes = ServletModule.class)
   public class MyModule {}

   @Module(injects = {...}, includes = ServletRequestModule.class)
   public class MyRequestModule {}

   public class MyServletContextListener extends DaggerServletContextListener {
       @Override
       protected Class[] getBaseModules() {
           return new Class[]{MyModule.class};
       }

   ```
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRequestScopedModules() {
       return new Class<?>[]{MyRequestModule.class};
   }
   ```

   }

Regards!